# Why can't an "AI export" from ArcGIS 10 be opened in CorelDRAW X5?

Tags: cartography, arcgis-10.0

It doesn't matter whether the .ai file is 1.5GB or 5MB, whether it's complex or simple; I always get the "The file cannot be opened." critical error.

I use CorelDRAW X5 not Adobe Illustrator but there should not be any issues since CorelDRAW opens and saves to and from AI without any issues whatsoever. Except for .ai files exported from ArcMap. There seem to be no issues with the PDF export. It opens in CorelDRAW fine and I can manipulate and edit vector graphics. However I would like to be able to use the AI output for my publishing work. (Layers, named objects, etc.)

Any workarounds?

Comment: Export .EMF from ArcMap - Import to CorelDraw X5 - Tip ungroup when in CorelDraw for Layers

Comment: The AI Export is buggy - We created our own export but took many hours of development sadly.

Comment: Thanks. Tried EMF. It opens but it's quite messed up.

Comment: Is your data grouped in ArcMap - you might need to separate it.

Comment: Not grouped. All individual layers. I think i will go back to the trusted tiff export.

Comment: You can also try to print into an EPS or PDF file, but the layers are likely to be mangled.

Comment: In ArcMap 8, export to PDF opened up in CorelDRAW like a dream. All layers and layer names preserved. Doesn't help with current versions. Just saying.